External HDMI monitor for android phone
I have an external HDMI display connected to an android phone via usb-c cable.
It mirrors a phone's screen to an external display successfully.
I would like to disable a phone screen to save energy and avoid any input for a time my application works and direct output only to an external display.
Is there any possibility to do this?
